# How to use JPA CriteriaBuilder selectCase() so that it can have Predicate as result?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I needed to implement a criteria query which has if...then...else scenario.
I found `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.selectCase()` is suitable for this purpose.It returns an `Expression` as result.

To run criteria query I needed to use `where()` which accepts an array of Predicates. This is because I have multiple predicates to include in the query.

Now, since `selectCase()` is returning `Expression`, I am not able to integrate it with existing list of Predicates.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Expression<Object> to Predicate
```

How do I use selectCase() so that I can have Predicate as result?
Or any other better way of doing this?

**Example:**

To illustrate the problem, I have following implementation to "Get all users of particular age AND (from a particular country and city) else from India, by default"

### if...then...else scenario

If from particular country

```
   if from particular city
```

else

```
 if from "India"
```

//  Query implementation

```
@Override
    public List<User> findUsersByAgeCountryAndCity(int age, String country, String city) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);

        Root<User> user = cq.from(User.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(age(user, age));

        predicates.add(country(user, country, city));

        cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    private Predicate country(Root<User> user, String country, String city) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        return cb.selectCase() //
                .when(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("country"), country),
                        cb.equal(user.get("address").get("city"), city))
                .otherwise(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("country"), "India")); 
    }

    private Predicate age(Root<User> entity, int age) {
        return entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().equal(entity.get("age"), age);
    }
```

//  User.java

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private LocalDate creationDate;
    private LocalDate lastLoginDate;
    private boolean active;
    private int age;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    private Integer status;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    @OneToMany
    List<Possession> possessionList;
...
```

//  Address.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String city;
    private String country;
...
```

Comment: What native SQL query are you trying to reproduce via Criteria API?

Comment: Actually I am trying to map an in-memory implementation into a JPA one. By in-memory I mean which is using maps and sets to store data and filters with predicates to query data.

Comment: I mean that CriteriaAPI query finally gets rendered into some SQL query like `select * from XXX where YYY`. And I'm asking what exact SQL query you wish to run

Answer (score 4):

If I read your question correctly, you want the following logic:

```
IF is_user_from_country 
    RETURN is_user_from_city
ELSE
    RETURN is_user_from_india
```

Making it into a query is tricky, because predicates in SQL do not have an intrinsic boolean value you can return. In SQL terms, it will look something like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN user.country = :country THEN
        CASE WHEN user.city = :city THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    WHEN user.country = 'India' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END
```

In Criteria API (note that I haven't tested it, there might be syntax errors):

```
cb.selectCase() //
    .when(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("country"), country),
            cb.selectCase()
            .when(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("city"), city), cb.literal(true))
            .otherwise(cb.literal(false))
    ))
    .when(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("country"), "India"), cb.literal(true))
    .otherwise(cb.literal(false));
```

I'm not entirely sure Criteria API supports nested `CASE` statements, though. If not, you can try making the logic more straightforward:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN user.country = :country AND user.city = :city THEN TRUE
    WHEN user.country = :country AND user.city <> :city THEN FALSE
    WHEN user.country = 'India' THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END
```

Comment: its in the similar lines as you explained. My main issue was to how to get Predicate from the method. With the above solution of nested case, I was getting Criteria Case as the result. Your second solution gave me a hint of cleaner solution. Explained below the answer. With this I am able to get Predicate as result. Please let me know if anything to be improved in the solution. Thanks

Comment: private Predicate country(Root<User> user, String country, String city) {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

  return cb.or(
    cb.and(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("country"), country),
      cb.equal(user.get("address").get("city"), city)),
    cb.and(cb.equal(user.get("address").get("country"), "India")));

 }