# Java Spring JPA: How to find the sum of only non null values in a column?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I currently have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.column1, SUM(t2.column2 IS NOT NULL)
FROM table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 on table.id = t2.id
GROUP BY column1, column2;
```

I am trying to implement the query using Spring JPA CriteriaBuilder. I see the CriteriaBuilder.sum() method, but I don't see a way to apply the IS NOT NULL part to the selection. Column2's data type is string.

Sample of my code

```
criteriaBuilder.multiselect(root.get("column1"), cb.sum(root.get("column2")));
```

Comment: Why not put "t2.column2 IS NOT NULL" into the WHERE clause?

Comment: How do you sum a string type?

Comment: `GROUP BY column1, column2` looks wrong as well.

Comment: It sums the number of non null records @Bohemian
The query works as expected in MYSQL.

Comment: @mvmn If I add "t2.column2 IS NOT NULL" into the WHERE clause, the left outer join will not work as expected. Adding a WHERE clause to the right table will cause the left outer join to be cancelled out.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I had to use GROUP BY in order to use SUM since it is an aggregated query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem. Thanks to @bohemian for helping me write a correct sum expression.

```
 final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
 final CriteriaQuery<Model1> cq = cb.createQuery(Model1.class);
 final Root<Model1> root = cq.from(Model1.class);
 final Join<Model1, Model1> selfJoin = 
     root.join("tableJoinColumn", JoinType.LEFT);
selfJoin.on(...);
cq.multiselect(root.get("column1"), cb.sum(cb.selectCase()
    .when(cb.isNull(selfJoin.get("column2")), 0).otherwise(1).as(Long.class)));
...
```

The self join required me to create an additional property on my model.
Model1.java

```
    /**
     * Property for LEFT INNER JOIN.
     */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Model1 tableJoinColumn;
```

[How to use JPA CriteriaBuilder selectCase() so that it can have Predicate as result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309212/how-to-use-jpa-criteriabuilder-selectcase-so-that-it-can-have-predicate-as-res)

[Self join in criteria query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253628/self-join-in-criteria-query)

Answer (score 2):

Only in MySQL would such a query run, due MySQL’s relaxed syntax rules.

In particular, in mysql `sum(column2 is not null)` is a *count*, not a *sum*. The expression `column2 is not null` is boolean and in mysql false is 0 and true is 1, so summing this expression is a mysql hack to count the number of times column2 is not null.

To convert it to standard sql:

```
select
    t.column1,
    count(t2.column2)
from table t
left join table t2 on t.id = t2.id
group by t.column1
```

This works because `count()` (and all aggregate functions) ignore nulls.

This version also corrects the errant column in the `group by` clause - in any other database, your query would have produced a “grouping by aggregate expression” error.

This query will produce the same result in MySQL as your current query.

Comment: Then how does the query work as expected in MYSQL? In MYSQL, SUM(column2 is not null) will sum the number of non null records in column2.

Comment: @MatthewS. in mysql, `SUM(column2 is not null)` is a *count*, not a *sum*. The expression `column2 is not null` is boolean and in mysql false is 0 and true is 1, so summing this expression is a mysql hack to *count* the number of times `column2` is not null. The non-hack, and portable, way is `sum(case when column2 is null then 0 else 1 end)`. Does that make sense and solve your problem?

Comment: That makes sense but that doesn't solve my problem of trying to convert the MYSQL query into something that can be used for Criteria Builder.